# How to fetch data from API given in Newline

Tags: java, newline

Part of my program's purpose is to retrieve data that is given in newline format from this api:http://ip-api.com/docs/api:newline_separated. The data are is concerned with the geo location of an IP address and is presented in Newline format; I only want to pull certain lines. I am not very familiar with URL/file i/o in Java and when I researched it I was a bit overwhelmed. I am able to access the data I want but I am struggling with understanding how to pull it into my program.

This is my method that will be used to access the data, pull certain lines, then convert it into variables to be used in the rest of the class:

```
public void getGeoLoc()
{
String locHolder;
try {
    geoLocRetriever = new URL("http://ip-api.com/line/" + MainDisplay.getAttackerIpHolder());
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
//BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(geoLocRetriever.openStream()));
}
```

Any input or suggested tutorial would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is the 444555 Java's question, you're welcome :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to read all the data from the stream.

```
InputStream stream = geoLocRetriever.openStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
if (stream != null) try {
    final BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(stream);
    final byte[] reader = new byte[16384];
    int r = 0;
    while ((r = input.read(reader, 0, 16384)) != -1)
        buffer.write(reader, 0, r);
    buffer.flush();
} catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if(stream != null) try {
        stream.close();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Convert that to a string.

```
locHolder = new String(buffer.toByteArray());
```

You can then split the lines using `String.split`.

```
String[] lines = locHolder.split("\n");
```

Using that you can then read the lines individually.

Comment: Thanks! that's very helpful. I believe that once I access the url, the lines are already split, is there any way in Java that I could just read certain lines? This should eb a sample output of the api: http://ip-api.com/line

Comment: Using lines, you can access the individual lines. So `lines[0]` will get the first line and `lines[1]` will get the second line and so forth.

Comment: Thanks @Chase. I'm curious though, is this the only way Java allows this to happen, that is, you must read all lines and then choose which to actually use in your program?

Comment: Pretty much. Any any language you have to read the contents in before you can access it. You could skip over data until you run into a `\n` character. But that wouldn't be any less complicated. Just ignore the lines you don't use. You can call `lines[4]` to jump directly to access line 5, without having to look at the other ones first, then later you can look at line 2 with `lines[1]`.

Comment: I have been using your suggested code and it's working well, I was hoping you could explain line by line what is happening so I can further expand my understanding of the subject. It would be greatly appreciated.